# How to fix smooth text in IE?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have a `WebBrowser` control in my application. I add a font to my CSS using this code:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'pNumber';
    src: 
    url('Address\pNumber.eot');
    url('Address\pNumber.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('Address\pNumber.woff')       format('woff'),
    url('Address\pNumber.ttf')        format('truetype'),
    url('Address\pNumber.svg#pNumber')    format('svg');
}
.pNumber 
{
    font-family: pNumber;
}
```

Every thing is fine but the text is not smooth. I find a lot of topics in Internet but no one could not solve this problem.
for example:

[Web fonts may appear blurry with Internet Explorer 7](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555778)

[How to Make ClearType, @font-face Fonts and CSS Visual Filters Play Nicely Together](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2010/09/02/how-to-make-cleartype-font-face-fonts-and-css-visual-filters-play-nicely-together/)

[@Font-Face Smoothing in IE](http://www.koodoz.com.au/klog/font-face-smoothing-in-internet-explorer/)

Comment: Since you've "already found" topics that don't work, why not list them so you people don't have to post responses on those topics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems IE needs hints in the fonts to display them correctly. I solved this problem by using [fontsquirrel's generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator) to create new font files. You can check which file IE is using by looking at the network activity in the developer tools.